# Python-shell problem after packaging my app with electron builder (Node Js)

Tags: python, node.js, electron, child-process, electron-builder

I finished my electron/node js & Python app (a steganography tool).
So I'd like to package it to distribute it on github with a dmg, exe...
So I installed electron-builder as my packager but when i package my app by taping: npm run dist or yarn run dist and that i open it: i get this results (just bellow)

[image]

It looks like a path problem but i have no idea how to solve that.
Thanks

Comment: And without code and context, we can't help you solve this either. From the error message I see that you haven't disabled ASAR, which most likely is the root of the problem, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68519797) (the first part) -- whilst Electron can read from the ASAR, your OS and Python can't.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner here's my repository without my python venv: https://github.com/Xam-Mlr/StegnHide

Comment: I have not the message anymore but now i got this: full failure Error: Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'